# Autodesk Viewer, Programmatic Camera Y-Axis Inversion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, 3d, autodesk-viewer

I have been using the markups core extension to get the viewer state and then restore it, which has been working, except I am running into an inversion problem (only in 3d). When a client interacts with specifically the y axis, and essentially flips the model to see underneath, or above, the viewer inverts itself, it seems during or after the [restoreState()](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewerstate/#restorestate-viewerstate-filter-immediate) function. The values are identical, just inverted, for example a client's `getState()` values of {x: 1, y: -1, z:-2} is restored and then inverted to {x: -1, y: 1, z: 2}.

To test this further, I used the `getCamera()`, took the position, the target, and the up value, and used `setView()` to programmatically set the camera position. What I found was without using the up, the optional value in the setView() function, the inversion repeated itself, the same effect, received the correct values, set them, then inverted. However this all fixed itself as soon as I used the up value. A new issue now is that the `setView()` function seems to lose the smooth transitioning of the camera that comes with `getState()` `restoreState()`, resulting in a very choppy and snappy UX. Knowing now that the issue lies somewhere in the up value I tried to go back to `setState()` `restoreState()` and try setting the up directly, this unfortunately did not work. I tried using `orientCameraUp(true)`, `setCameraUpVector()` with both the `getState().viewport.up` and `getState().viewport.worldUpVector`.

1. Is it possible to fix this inversion with the `getState()`, `restoreState()` so we can keep the smoothness of the transition?
2. Is it possible to replicate the smooth transition of the `restoreState()` to use the method that had worked, `setView()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replicate smooth camera transitions while having control over the up vector, you can use the `viewer.navigation.setRequestTransitionWithUp` method. For some reason the docs and params for this method are not showing up in the [documentation](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Navigation/), so let me add it here:

```
/**
 * Issue a request to transition the current cameras view to that specified
 * by the parameters which inlude both the camera up direction and optionally
 * the world up direction.
 *
 *  @param {boolean} state - value of the requst. Set to true in order to request the change of view.
 *  @param {THREE.Vector3} pos - the new camera position in world space
 *  @param {THREE.Vector3} coi - the point in world space that the camera should look towards.
 *  @param {number} fov - vertical field of view in degrees
 *  @param {THREE.Vector3} up -  use this as the target camera up direction
 *  @param {THREE.Vector3} [worldUp] - (optional) use this as the target world up direction
 *  @param {THREE.Vector3} [pivot] - (optional) the new pivot point
 */
```

Comment: And as for the `getState` and `restoreState` flipping the up axis, I'll report that to the viewer team. Thank you for the heads up!